# How do I solve the integral: $\int x^2\ln(x^6-1)dx$ using integration by parts?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

As the title says I need to solve: $\int x^2\ln(x^6-1)dx$.
Now I said that $$\int x^2\ln(x^6-1)dx=\frac{x^3\ln(x^6-1)}{3}-\int \frac{6x^8}{3(x^6-1)}dx=\frac{x^3\ln(x^6-1)}{3}-2\int \frac{x^8}{(x^6-1)}dx$$.
The problem is I do not see any way to solve:$\int \frac{x^8}{(x^6-1)}dx$.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by factoring the expression in your logarithm and turn this into

$$\int{x^2 \ln(x^3+1)}\, dx + \int{x^2 \ln(x^3-1)}\, dx.$$

Both of these are integrals of the form $\int \ln u\, du$, which can be solved by integration by parts.

Comment: Very nice approach!

Comment: I did like you said and I got that it is equal to $\frac{(x^3+1)ln(x^6-1)-2x^3}{3}$ but if I derivate it I do not get $x^2ln(x^6-1)$.

Comment: Sorry. I realised what I did wrong. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $u=x^3\implies\mathrm{d}u=3x^2\mathrm{d}x$ this changes the integral into $\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}u$ which can be solved by long division then partial fractions

Comment: I am not able to use integration by substitution cause I did not learn it yes. Can it be solve without that?

Comment: It is possible but may take a significantly longer time. You can long divide and then partial fraction $\frac{1}{x^6-1}$ which would take a long time